# How to change the weight of a pin line in PGF Plots?

Tags: pgfplots

Using pins is a nice way to annote your plots in PGF Plots. However, I would like to have the weight for the line leading from a point on the graph to the text to be bold. How do I do this?

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain=1:6]
        {exp(x)};
        54.59815
        \node[coordinate,pin=left:{A pin!}]
            at (axis cs:4,54.59815) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To modify a single pin, you can use `pin edge`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain=1:6]
        {exp(x)};
        54.59815
        \node[coordinate,pin={[pin edge={blue,ultra thick}]left:{A pin!} } ]
            at (axis cs:4,54.59815) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To change the format for all pins, you can change the `every pin edge` style.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! May I ask two questions? 1. How did you find this out? I am still learning TikZ and have trouble finding such information. At least I was too blind to see it in the manual, if it is in there. 2. Could I add an arrow tip to the pin? Thanks again!

Comment: @Ingo You're welcome! Regarding your questions: 1. pages 196 and 197 of the pgfmanual contain basic information about pins; in particular, `pin edge` and `every pin edge`. 2. Of course, you can use the arrow syntax for `pin edge`:  you can use something like `\node[coordinate,pin={[pin edge={<-,blue,ultra thick}]left:{A pin!} } ]` in the code above.

Comment: Just to add, if you want this style to apply to all `pin` use:
`\tikzset{
    every pin edge/.append style={blue, thick}
    }`

Comment: What are the options available for the size, `thick`, `ultra thick`, ...?